# How to count the 2nd number at the equal button

Tags: c#

I want to add a new function to my calculator. If I do `1 + 1` and press the `equal` button, the outcome will be `2`. The function I want to add is that if I press the `equal` button again, there will be `1` added to `2`, so the outcome is `3`. When I click again on the `equal` button this must happen again and the outcome must be `4`. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string first = "";
        string second = "";
        string userInput = "";
        string space = " ";
        char function;
        double result = 0.0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void number1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "1";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "2";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "3";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "4";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "5";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "6";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "7";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "8";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "9";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            first = "";
            second = "";
            userInput = "";
            result = 0.0;
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "0";
            feedback.Text = "";

        }

        private void divideButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '/';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "÷";
            
        }

        private void multiplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '*';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "*";
        }

        private void plusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '+';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "+";


        }

        private void minusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '-';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "-";
 
        }

        private void equalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            second = userInput;
            double firstNum, secondNum;
            firstNum = Convert.ToDouble(first);
            secondNum = Convert.ToDouble(second);
            if(function =='+')
            {
                result = firstNum + secondNum;
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = first +  space + "+" + space + second + space + "=";               
            }
            else if(function == '-')
            {
                result = firstNum - secondNum;
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = first + space + "-" + space + second + space + "=";
            }
            else if (function == '/')
            {
                if(secondNum == 0)
                {
                    calculatorDisplay.Text = "Error";
                }
                else
                {
                    result = firstNum / secondNum;
                    calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                    feedback.Text = first + space + "÷" + space + second + space + "=";
                }
            }
            else if (function == '*')
            {
                result = firstNum * secondNum;
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = first + space + "*" + space + second + space + "=";
            }
        }

        private void decimalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            calculatorDisplay.Text += ".";
        }

        private void zeroButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "0";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you do `20 - 5` and press `=` twice?

Comment: Where must I try that in my code?

Comment: It is not for your code, the question is how do you expect your calculator to behave when you do that?

Comment: Okay, I expect for the output 10. Because 20 - 5 = 15. And when I press "=" again there must be 5 substracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would scale down the click methods like so:

```
private void equalsClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput ++;
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }
```

And then for this I would go with

```
if(function =='+')
            {
                result = (secondNum * userInput) + firstNum   ;
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                double newSecond = (second * userInput);
                feedback.Text = first +  space + "+" + space + newSecond + space + "=";               
            }
```

If that makes sense. You want to count the times the user clicked. Just be sure to reset userClick to 0 on clearButton

Comment: Yes, and when I click for the second time on the equal button the outcome must be 15 and when i click for the thirth time it must be 20. If you open a calculator on your computer you understand what I mean, I think. When you do 5+5 in the calculator the outcome is 10 and when you click again on the equal button it will add the second input number

Comment: So it is a multiplication thing like I thought. I will edit my answer

Comment: Okay, thank you, because I don't know where I must put it in my code

Comment: I get an error that the operator ++ can't be applied to the string input. Btw must I delete what I have in my void equalbuttonclick?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two variables declared in the class like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double result =0.00;
    double lastnumber = 0.00;
}
```

So you will in the button click event assign values to these two variables like below:

```
    private void number1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        lastnumber = userInput;
        result = result + lastnumber;
        calculatorDisplay.Text =result;
        
    }
```

And If you don't know much about recursive functions or usages avoid the use of it to perform these functions.

Comment: Okay, but where must I put it in the if statement of equalButton_Click? Because when I just put it under the other code in an if statement, it says already after 1 equal click that 5+5=15