# How can I add the second number to the equal button?

Tags: c#

want to add a new function to my calculator. If I do 1 + 1 and press the equal button, the outcome will be 2. The function I want to add is that if I press the equal button again, there will be 1 added to 2, so the outcome is 3. When I click again on the equal button this must happen again and the outcome must be 4. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string first = "";
        string second = "";
        string userInput = "";
        string space = " ";
        char function;
        double result = 0.0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void number1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "1";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "2";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "3";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "4";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "5";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "6";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "7";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "8";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "9";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            first = "";
            second = "";
            userInput = "";
            result = 0.0;
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "0";
            feedback.Text = "";

        }

        private void divideButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '/';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "÷";
            
        }

        private void multiplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '*';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "*";
        }

        private void plusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '+';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "+";


        }

        private void minusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '-';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "-";
 
        }

        private void equalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            second = userInput;
            double firstNum, secondNum;
            firstNum = Convert.ToDouble(first);
            secondNum = Convert.ToDouble(second);
            if(function =='+')
            {
                result = firstNum + secondNum;
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = first +  space + "+" + space + second + space + "=";               
            }
            else if(function == '-')
            {
                result = firstNum - secondNum;
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = first + space + "-" + space + second + space + "=";
            }
            else if (function == '/')
            {
                if(secondNum == 0)
                {
                    calculatorDisplay.Text = "Error";
                }
                else
                {
                    result = firstNum / secondNum;
                    calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                    feedback.Text = first + space + "÷" + space + second + space + "=";
                }
            }
            else if (function == '*')
            {
                result = firstNum * secondNum;
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = first + space + "*" + space + second + space + "=";
            }
        }

        private void decimalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            calculatorDisplay.Text += ".";
        }

        private void zeroButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "0";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the value of `first` variable to the answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this on principle because you simply asked it again rather than work to improve your previous, closed question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70777029/how-to-count-the-2nd-number-at-the-equal-button).

Comment: @adv12 I improved my question. What could be better then, do you think?

Comment: I meant edit your old question as opposed to asking a slightly differently worded version of the question, throwing away the effort of everyone who commented on and attempted to answer that question.  Your old one got closed because it lacked focus.  I recommend you go back to that question and work to give it focus.

Comment: Okay, thanks for you feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already most of the way there.  `equalButton_Click` works by applying the operation specified by `function` and `second` to `first`.  So if you say `1 + 1 =`, you get a result of 2.  If you want to hit `=` again and get the result from `2 + 1 =`, all you'd need to do is have your code put `result` into `first` and you've (conceptually) got a solution that works.

Having said that, the constant conversions between `string` and `double`, plus [floating-point precision errors](https://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html) are going to ensure it doesn't work particularly well for anything complicated.  If you want this code to be anything more than a toy, look into better methods of dealing with exact numbers.

Comment: Okay thank you very much!